# jars getting loaded twice in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, struts2

Problem: `jar` getting loaded twice in eclipse

Description:
I copied and pasted struts `jar` into lib folder of `WEB-INF`.
The jars icon get changed .
If I remove the `jars` in build path they get back to normal state but program says package not found.
My program is correct but i am getting

> Resource not found ie HTTP-404

error due to this.

So please tell me how to load `jars`?

Comment: Not enough information to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do two things

1. go to the build path and create user define library for you jar file and
2. when you deleting it from build path that mean it is not configured for you application but some times it shows like it is configured. For that you again go to lib and add the jar to build path